# How to periodicaly run function in Python on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

I am working on a python server (running on GAE) for my browser game. Everything was working fine until now. I can't run Timer on GAE, so I don't know, how to periodicaly inform all clients about changes at the server.

My current idea was, that clients send messages to server. Server manages recieved data and in some short interval sends updates to all connected clients. But I can't run Timer, so I don't know, how to do it.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks Toneks

Edit: I forgot to say, that I need very small interval to be very small - like 100ms. So Cron isn't very good solution.

Comment: Can you provide more detail as to what the `Timer` you can't run is?

Comment: If you want a higher frequency than cron can implement  (say every 100ms) , use a permanently running backend, that is effectively your game clock/timer.  Not sure how useful a timer of that frequency will be.  A lot network latencies will be longer than that especially mobile/3g.

Answer (score 2):

Use App Engine's [Cron Service](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html#About_cron_yaml) for this

> A cron.yaml file in the root directory of your application (alongside app.yaml) configures scheduled tasks for your Python application

Comment: Is it possible? I thought, that Cron can't run tasks so frequently (like every 100ms).

Answer (score 0):

If your updates are to be sent out based on other user events (or even server events) consider using the [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/). This way, you only send out updates as they're needed to the users that require the updates.

If you need the server to periodically run through some code, using the [Cron Service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=it#About_cron_yaml) as Oscar suggested is the best way to go.